# a2dp and Bluetooth audio codecs

Tags: audio, bluetooth, nxp-microcontroller, a2dp

I have a question about Bluetooth codecs and a2dp. I have a evk i.mxrt1040 from NXP and used the a2dp_sink example it uses the sbc codec, with 16 bit depth, and 48 KHz sample rate and it works fine. Using my phone to connect and stream music to the device from the phone, and listening it on the headphones of the device.

What I want is to use 24 bit depth if I change the bit depth it is just noise, by searching the internet I run into Bluetooth codecs for a2dp (sbc,aac,ldac...). And ldac and aac are using 24 bits.

Can sbc codec work with 24 bit depth?
Who provides the code for the Bluetooth codecs?. Is it the Bluetooth stack?